# Debugging options in R

Tags: r, debugging

In some coding languages, the cursor stops in debug mode before the error happened in the local environment of the function being run. I am wondering if there is a similar functionality in R.

Currently what I found from researching this matter:

- To reproduce that in R, we need to position "browser()" at a strategic location we think of. Then recompile the function we were running by selecting all the lines of the function then hitting CTRL + Enter to compile it then run the code then debug in the function. If browser was improperly positioned due to bad guessing this operation has to be repeated causing significant time loss.
  It is very painful.
- Another solution I found that is even worse is the use of options(error = recover). If we are going through iterations for example, it will be offer to stop before the loop started instead of offering to jump in the code at the iteration that caused the bug. This feature does not seem to be much more helpful.

Comment: You might check out the debugging tools in rstudio. The newest version has improved tools such as setting up breakpoints.

Comment: your terminology about "compilation" isn't exactly correct -- you're redefining the function, not recompiling the code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is too long/formatted for a comment.)  I'm not sure what you mean (referring to `options(error=recover)` by

> it will be offer to stop before the loop started instead of offering to jump in the code at the iteration that caused the bug.

Here's an example where the break seems to occur at the iteration that caused the error, as requested:

```
options(error=recover)
f <- function(x) { for (i in 1:x) if (i==2) stop() }
f(5)
Error in f(5) : 
Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   
1: f(5)
Selection: 1
Called from: top level 
Browse[1]> print(i)
[1] 2
```

This is breaking at a specific step in the loop, not (as suggested above) before the loop starts (where `i` would be undefined).

Can you please give a reproducible example to clarify the difference between the behaviour that happens and what you'd prefer?

For what it's worth, the RStudio front-end offers a slightly more visual debugging experience that you might prefer.

Comment: Ben, you are right concerning the options(error = recover)
I am already using R studio. Apart from the tools I described would you have any other recommendations?

What is the fastest way to redefine a function? Is it CTRL enter?
Thanks

Comment: I think RStudio has a keyboard shortcut for "hot-paste body of current function [i.e. the function the cursor is in] to R session" -- that would be slightly more convenient than having to select the function explicitly.  Depending on your workflow, if you have your functions defined in a separate file you can `source("myfuns.R")` to re-define them, or hit a "source file" button in RStudio.

Comment: Ben,
One last question I will ask you. When it comes to hiding lines, it is pretty easy for a function but for code outside of a function I only was able to find  ALT L that requires the hidden region to be commented. Is there anything you use?

Comment: I don't actually use RStudio.  Maybe you could ask another question, either here or (perhaps more usefully) on the RStudio forums.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can close out this question -- if you think my answer is useful/resolves your question, you can click on the check-mark. If you think it doesn't resolve your question, you can edit your question to clarify what you're looking for (but please don't take it *too* far from the original version). If you think the question and answer are actually useless (to you and to future readers), you can delete it.  If you think it's not useful for you but useful for future readers, you can ask high-rep users to close it.